# react useRef focus doesn't show keyboard on iPhone

Tags: reactjs, iphone

I have a react app where on mobile the user can click an icon to see a search input bar. The focus should go to the input element and show the keyboard if on mobile. The problem is the cursor doesn't move to the input element and the keyboard doesn't display on iPhone. Does anyone know of a fix for this?

In parent component:

```
const [focusSearchInput, setFocusSearchInput] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (isMobile) {
     setFocusSearchInput(true);
  }
}, [isMobile]);
```

child component:

```
const inputRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  focusSearchInput ? inputRef?.current?.focus() : inputRef?.current?.blur();
}, [focusSearchInput]);

return (
  <input ref={inputRef} />
)
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it? Do the effects run at the moment you expect them to run? Is the inputRef initialized by then?

Comment: Browsers are usually restrictive of automatically performing actions for the user such as copying or entering full screen. I don't know if this is the case for you but you can try to focus the input inside the actual onClick event and see if that does the trick. Otherwise, perhaps safari still thinks the input is hidden and refuses to focus, in which case use a setTimeout of no delay focus there.

Comment: If you just want it to be automatically focused when it first mounts, you can use `autoFocus` instead.

Comment: @Undo you're right! Once I moved it to the actual click event it worked

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are usually restrictive of automatically performing actions for the user such as copying or entering full screen. Focus the input inside the actual onClick event instead of doing it inside a useEffect.